# Block ip addresses automatically using PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip-address, block

I have a login system that I am trying to make as secure as possible. After ten failed attempts, I would like to block the IP address. How can I open a file in PHP and add a line to my .htaccess file to block the IP Address? Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on

# Block IP addresses with too many failed attempts
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^217.172.179.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^217.172.180.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/error/blocked.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error/blocked.php [R,NC,L]
```

I would like the PHP file to add the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^IPHERE$ [OR]
```

in the appropriate spot.

Comment: ip does not = person, an attacker (or regular user) would go though a range of ips.

Comment: I know that, the code will just keep blocking the new ip every ten attempts

Comment: @ethanh: That doesn't sound very wise. Blocking IPs permanently usually doesn't end well (as normal users attempt to use your site and fail due to IP blocking).

Comment: yup, and any serious attacker go through a few hundred open proxy's every minute. there is server software designed to this that will do a much better job than you ever will

Comment: There is a form with a recaptcha to unblock it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend editing the .htaccess file directly.

Instead, have a file or a database table to save all of the blacklisted IP addresses, and test against that in PHP, rather than on Apache's side.

Comment: The problem with that though, is that my host doesn't allow heavy database usage. I pretty much need to use htaccess. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @ethanh get a decent host perhaps?

Comment: @Ethanh the problem with editing the htaccess if you make a mistake/syntax error your whole site under the htaccess will display 500 internal server error.

Comment: Heavy? Each IP address is maximum 15 characters long, even at a staggering 10000 IP addresses blacklisted, that's less than 150K of data. If that's too much for your host, you better switch host. Also, you have the option to use files.

Comment: Is there any way to do it though?

Comment: @ethanh: Use a file (blacklist.txt) and save all of the IP addresses there, one on each line. Then compare the connecting IP to the list with PHP. See [Teh Manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Why isn't this working?

    <?php
    $file=fopen("blacklist.txt","r+");
    $search = '#newiphere';
    $replace = '#ipentered';
    str_replace ($search, $replace, $file);
    fclose($file);
    ?>

The contents of blacklist.txt is:

    #newiphere

Why isn't it replacing?

Comment: @ethanh: You are not writing to the file anywhere. Please read the WHOLE section on file functions, and understand exactly how to work with them, before you actually try to.